# How to commit changes of navigator bar translucency properly?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

I have faced with such problem.
I have two VC. One of it has basic navigator bar, which inherits from main Navigator bar. 
In this nav bar I use such settings to customise my nav nar

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationBar.createGradientNavigatorBar()

    navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.init(red: 0/255, green: 97/255, blue: 185/255, alpha: 1)
    navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()

}
```

On the second VC I have to set custom gradient background which connected with view. For this purpose I have extended my view up to bar height and make par transculent. Here is code:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    isCurrentViewControllerAppropriate.shared.isCurrentVcAppropriate = isCurrentViewController()

    let firstColor = UIColor.init(red: 0/255, green: 94/255, blue: 198/255, alpha: 1)
    let secondColor = UIColor.init(red: 27/255, green: 145/255, blue: 226/255, alpha: 1)

    profileBackgroundView.createGradient(firstColor: firstColor.cgColor, secondColor: secondColor.cgColor)

    navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
}
```

Everything is working fine, but I have rough transition between vc. I've attached.
As you may notice when I return to my first VC is loading it have an artefact with navigator bar color from second VC, which resolves after a certain period of time. I have no idea how to deal with it

[image]

I'm not sure whether my approach is the right one, so I'll be glad to hear any advices consider solving this issue.

Comment: Try by writing code in the viewDidApprear method which called when view controller fully appear.

Comment: I've tried, but that didn't help me either

Comment: Hide navigation bar in `viewWillDisappear`